# How to stop couchDb view from displaying all documents if no query or "key" parameter is passed

Tags: couchdb

I am new to couchDB and i have created a view with following function:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc._id){
  emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

So on executing :

```
curl -X GET "http://<usr>:<pass>@<domain>:5984/test_users/_design/user_data/_view/myview"
```

It returns ids of all available documents.

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"bbbe46366d0d2fafa53442abdb000252","key":"bbbe46366d0d2fafa53442abdb000252","value":null},
{"id":"bbbe46366d0d2fafa53442abdb000255","key":"bbbe46366d0d2fafa53442abdb000255","value":null}
]}
```

I want to **stop** it from listing all these documents when no query parameter is given to it. 
I made multiple google searches but didn't get any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bigger question is how the result values are null (as indicated in the OP) when the map function is emitting the doc, implied by the if-statement as non-null, is null?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention , I have removed the doc data as it was sensitive.

Comment: OK good to have that clarification, sometimes odd bugs can be revealed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason no answer can be found on the internet is that the answer does not exist because that *behavior* does not exist.

As documented at [1.5.4.4. Using Limits and Skipping Rows](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=limit#using-limits-and-skipping-rows)

> By default, views return all results. That’s ok when the number of
> results is small, but this may lead to problems when there are
> billions results, since the client may have to read them all and
> consume all available memory.

Of course one could theoretically fork the CouchDB sources and modify the server code to provide a default limit - but that is not feasible.

The method to control the number of documents is with the `limit` parameter.  1.5.4.4 documentation discusses how to use `limit` and `skip` to control pagination.

Also, a few comments about your map function:

- The map function is duplicating the [_all_docs endpoint](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html?highlight=_all_docs#db-all-docs). *Don't do that.*
- emitting a doc as a value is redundant and will bloat your database.  *Don't do that.* Instead use [include_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=limit#get--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view)

Comment: Thanks for the limit and skip!